# SQL - Logica de Consulta

Tags: sql-server

Estou quebrando a cabeça com uma situação quero trazer um retorno de uma consulta considerando apenas dias uteis.

Esta tabela possui a lista de usuários:

[image: Tabela1]

Esta tabela é preenchida pelos usuários:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quero que a consulta me retorne os dias não preenchidos pelos usuários, desconsiderando sábados e domingos, desta forma o resultado da consulta ficaria assim:**Consulta entre 05/09 e 10/09**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como solução pensei em ao criar o usuário já inserir as datas na tabela de preenchimento, e para ter o resultado que quero simplesmente consultar os registro que a coluna valor estiver zerada.

Gostaria de saber se há forma melhor de fazer algo assim, pois estou iniciando com programação.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Quero que a consulta me retorne os dias não preenchidos pelos usuários, desconsiderando sábados e domingos,*

Jorge, a sugestão é que armazene na tabela `Preenchimento` somente os eventos que ocorreram e que no momento de execução da consulta é que seja montada a tabela de dias úteis do período.

Por exemplo:

```
-- código #1
declare @DataInicial date, @DataFinal date;
set dateformat dmy;
-- informe as datas no formato dd/mm/aaaa
set @DataInicial= cast('5/9/2018' as date);
set @DataFinal= cast('20/9/2018' as date);

--
set datefirst 1;  -- semana inicia na segunda-feira
with 
Datas as (
SELECT @DataInicial as Dia
union all 
SELECT dateadd(day, +1, Dia)
  from Datas 
  where Dia < @DataFinal
),
DxU as (
SELECT U.Vendedor, D.Dia
  from Datas as D
       cross join Usuário as U
  where datepart(dw, D.Dia) <= 5
        -- and Dia não é feriado
)
SELECT DU.Vendedor, DU.Dia
  from DxU as DU
  where not exists (SELECT * 
                      from Preenchimento as P
                      where P.Dia = DU.Dia 
                            and P.Vendedor = DU.Vendedor);
```

Para facilitar a compreensão e manutenção do código foram utilizadas CTE (common table expressions) para implementar programação modular, conforme consta no artigo “[Programação modular com expressões de tabela (CTE)](https://portosql.wordpress.com/2018/09/23/programacao-modular-com-expressoes-de-tabela-cte/)”.

A CTE `Datas` gera os dias no período. Pode-se acompanhar isso ao isolar a primeira parte do código #1:

```
-- código #1 parte 1
declare @DataInicial date, @DataFinal date;
set dateformat dmy;
-- informe as datas no formato dd/mm/aaaa
set @DataInicial= cast('5/9/2018' as date);
set @DataFinal= cast('20/9/2018' as date);

--
with 
Datas as (
SELECT @DataInicial as Dia
union all 
SELECT dateadd(day, +1, Dia)
  from Datas 
  where Dia < @DataFinal
)
SELECT Dia
  from Datas;
```

A segunda CTE, `DxU`, filtra as datas para manter somente de segunda a sexta-feira na CTE e também realiza o produto cartesiano com a tabela de usuários existentes.

```
-- código #1 parte 2
declare @DataInicial date, @DataFinal date;
set dateformat dmy;
-- informe as datas no formato dd/mm/aaaa
set @DataInicial= cast('5/9/2018' as date);
set @DataFinal= cast('20/9/2018' as date);

--
set datefirst 1;  -- semana inicia na segunda-feira
with 
Datas as (
SELECT @DataInicial as Dia
union all 
SELECT dateadd(day, +1, Dia)
  from Datas 
  where Dia < @DataFinal
),
DxU as (
SELECT U.Vendedor, D.Dia
  from Datas as D
       cross join Usuário as U
  where datepart(dw, D.Dia) <= 5
        -- and Dia não é feriado
)
SELECT Vendedor, Dia
  from DxU;
```

Observe que se deseja dias úteis necessitará também de tabela de feriados (locais, estaduais e nacionais). Você encontra soluções para implementá-la no artigo “[Operações com dias úteis no SQL Server](https://portosql.wordpress.com/2020/12/02/operando-dias-uteis/)”.

Não testei o código; pode conter erro(s).

Comment: Obrigado José agora tenho uma direção, vou pegar o código e esmiuçar.